# Show categories from a table in Tree structure

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to show categories in a drop-down with tree structure. I have a table with following structure

```
ID     Category      Level       Reference 
1      First            1          0
2      Second           1          0
3      Third            1          0
4      First's child 1  2          1
5      First's child 2  2          1
6      Next level       3          5
```

**Level**

Is this the hierarchy level. If level is 1, then first level and 2 is the child of first and so on.

**Reference**

This field shows who is the parent. It is the reference of parent categories Id.

I want to show this data as follows:

```
First
   First's child 1
   First's child 2
      Next level
Second
Third
```

How can i show the data as above in a select box?

Comment: Are you just looking for a way to indent it, or are you at the stage where you need to find a way to get things listed in the correct order? Is there any code you tried already you might want to share?

Answer (score 1):

You can get your level and category name through your database, then loop it like this, for example :

```
echo '<select>';
foreach ($yourResult as $result) {
  echo '<option>'.str_repeat("&nbsp;",$result['level']).$result['category'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

[See an example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L0emkf4k/1/)

**Doc :** http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php